# How do I remove default markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm using Google Map API V3 and I noticed there are a lot of markers which are here even though I don't need them. For examples, some schools or other places with InfoWindows appearing when clicking on them.

Is there any way I can remove them or is it just not possible?

Comment: If you want an example: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html

Zoom on NYC for example you can see a lot of Point of interest that are clickable.

For example: "City University of New York Brooklyn College
 - more info »
2900 Bedford Avenue, New York, NY 11210, United States"

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The only markers that should show up on the map are those you add yourself.  Care to share your code or a page where we can see this happening?

Update: ok, these aren't really 'markers' in the normal sense of the word, they're just points of interest, which happen to behave like markers in that you can click on them and see infowindows.  It seems to me that these might be of the class [MapTypeStyleFeatureType](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyleFeatureType), probably of types like poi.medical, poi.park, transit.station.rail and so on.  I wonder if you could use the MapTypeStyle.  Maybe something like this:

```js
var myStyles =[
    {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
              { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
];

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: homeLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: myStyles 
};
```

You might also want to look at the [Styled Map Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

Update, July 2016: The Maps API also now has an option you can specify in the MapOptions, `clickableIcons`, which if you set to false, the icons for these POIs will appear but clicking them doesn't open Google's infowindows.  This saves you having to set the styles to hide the icons unless you want to, if all you need to do is prevent the clicks opening the infowindows.
Just set `clickableIcons: false` in the options you initialise the Map with.

Comment: I added an example, you have to zoom enough to see those points.

Comment: Thank you! These POI's should be turned off by default in the APi.

Comment: Styled Map Wizard link is broken, but I supposed has moved here: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Answer (score 12):

You might have a look at [custom styled maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).

There is also a [wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com) that helps to build the options array.

Comment: And do you know how to use the style created in the Google Cloud console in your map? I can't get it to work.