# How do I turn off Points of Interest in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

Using jquery-mobile with javascript, how would I turn off the Google Maps POI Points of Interest.  I only want to show my markers on the map and nothing else.  Right now it shows restaurants, businesses, parks, parking ect.  I don't want any of that!

styles?  featureType? poi?  Not sure how to format it in my mapOptions

```
var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 15,
              center: myLatlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              streetViewControl: false

            };
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538444/how-do-i-remove-default-markers