# Google Maps API: Capturing clicks on markers I didn't create

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Using [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) along with several others it's pretty easy to figure out how to put markers on maps in different situations whether from a search or from my own data. However, when I use the google examples I sometimes see places on the map that I didn't add. For example, a search for an exact address will put a marker there, but often also shows small icons for various local businesses. Clicking on these opens that business's details in a popup and gives the user a chance to see more about the place.

My question has several parts.

1. Is it possible to get capture the click event for those icons so I can show my own popup instead?
2. If not, is it possible to tell the map to not show any markers or icons that I didn't place?

**Edit: ** This is not a duplicate of the listed question. That deals with markers, but these are not markers. See the comments for a link to the question that this is really a duplicate of.

Comment: There is no way to "getAllMarkers()", Google recommends using your own array to track them so I suspect that what you are seeing on the map isn't a google.map.Marker.

Comment: Regarding the POI (points of interest) you can hide them by customizing your mapOptions object. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538444/how-do-i-remove-default-markers