# Android Google Maps v2 remove default markers

Tags: android, google-maps

I implemented Android Google Maps v2 in my Android app without any problem.

However, the map includes some "default markers" that I haven't included.

I mean, some private business locations.

Is it possible to remove these markers from the map so that I only get the city names and the street names?

Comment: it's worth mentioning this link to help generate map styles: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markers you mean to say google places , If yes then we cant.
to remove markers that are added by 
`googleMap.addMarker()` method that can be remove by

```
marker.remove()
```

or by clearing marker

```
googleMap.clear()
```

Comment: Exactly, I would like to remove Google places from my map.

Comment: Then you can try some other map options for plain map.

Comment: you can if you know what you're talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538444/how-do-i-remove-default-markers

Comment: @MuhammadFarhanArif, hope you read the answer and understand what I said.

Comment: I am agreed with the answer of Jozef, And in my answer I have clearly mention all the things what the code does and what not.

Answer (score 33):

You can do it simply by modification of the map style: [Adding a Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling)

1. Create JSON file **src\main\res\raw\map_style.json** like this:

```json
[
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      {
        visibility: "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

2. Add map style to your `GoogleMap`

```java
googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks to @Jozef

Comment: Note that the style to remove the default POI's only works on the plain map type, not on hybrid for example.