# Google map not show all places

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I integrated the google map to my app. But some places do not show on it. I think the fact is that the map does not show shops inside shopping centers and the like. I checked the Credentials, but there everything is enabled. I thought the matter was    in this method    `mGoogleMap.setIndoorEnabled()` but when I set the value `true` I did not get any effect.

Attached 2 screenshots (in web browser in all ok, also in ios app with google map all ok):
[image: screenshot 1 - whithout all places]
[image: screenshot 1 - with all places]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed `GoogleMap` object not show all places by default. Seems you should use [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) from [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) and get list of points of interest via nearby URL request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<LAT_LNG_e_g_ 32.944552,-97.129767>&types=point_of_interest&radius=<RADIUS_IN_METERS>&sensor=false&key=<YOUR_APP_KEY>
```

parse it and show desired places on map programmatically.

NB! Nearby URL request returns only 20 places, for load more data you should use string value from `next_page_token` tag of response and pass it via `pagetoken` parameter for next request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<LAT_LNG_e_g_ 32.944552,-97.129767>&types=point_of_interest&radius=<RADIUS_IN_METERS>&sensor=false&key=<YOUR_APP_KEY>&pagetoken=<TOKEN_FOR_NEXT_PAGE_FROM_next_page_token_TAG_OF_RESPONSE>
```

Before add markers of POI may be you need to hide "standard" markers, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090477/6950238) answer of [Jozef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4239860/jozef):

> You can do it simply by modification of the map style: [Adding a
>   Styled
>   Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling)
>
> 1. Create JSON file **src\main\res\raw\map_style.json** like this:
>
> ```
> [
>   {
>     featureType: "poi",
>     elementType: "labels",
>     stylers: [
>       {
>         visibility: "off"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```
>
> 2. Add map style to your `GoogleMap`
>
> ```
> googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style));
> ```

And don't forget to enable Places API for your application from [Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend).

Or, you can do the trick: use simple `WebView` instead of `MapFragment` and open it for necessary place:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=32.944552,-97.129767&z=20");
```

`WebView` shows same Points of Interest as web browser.