# How to remove unnecessary marks and places in google map for android app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to remove unnecessary marks and places in google map for an android developer? I'm trying to show some places, but when user zoom-in bunch of places and marks show in map which is pretty normal, but all i want is to remove them and show only my marks. check below image :

Well as u can see in below image, blue circle is my icons and red are belong to google map, i just want my icons show in app.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this link will help you [Android Google Maps v2 remove default markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090477/7615169). I tested it and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. link with customization did the job.