# Android Google Map API cumstom marker bring Google map data on custom marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-styling, point-of-interest

I'm trying to build an Android application that needs to show some places on the map with custom markers. When the marker clicked it shows the snippet, however, for my application I need to show the Google maps info about the place as in Google Maps application shows. My XML is simple:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've two problems:

1. The Points of Interest from Google Maps are not clickable. Their icon visible on the map but they are not clickable.
2. When my custom marker clicked I want to show the Google map's info, not my snippet.

Are there ways to achieve these?

Comment: Is this api that you need to get data about place? https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details

Comment: @VadimEksler This might help, but isn't it possible to bring just the Google maps info windows? So, that the use can see the comments etc.

Comment: I don't think that even possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For p.1:**

At first hide all "default" Points of Interest from Google Maps like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090477/6950238) answer of [Jozef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4239860/jozef):

> You can do it simply by modification of the map style: [Adding a
>   Styled
>   Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling)
>
> 1. Create JSON file **src\main\res\raw\map_style.json** like this:
>
> ```
> [
>   {
>     featureType: "poi",
>     elementType: "labels",
>     stylers: [
>       {
>         visibility: "off"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```
>
> 2. Add map style to your `GoogleMap`
>
> ```
> googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style));
> ```

Than use [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) from [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) and get list of points of interest via nearby URL request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<LAT_LNG_e_g_ 32.944552,-97.129767>&types=point_of_interest&radius=<RADIUS_IN_METERS>&sensor=false&key=<YOUR_APP_KEY>
```

parse it and show desired places on map programmatically as yours clickable markers.

NB! Nearby URL request returns only 20 places, for load more data you should use string value from `next_page_token` tag of response and pass it via `pagetoken` parameter for next request:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<LAT_LNG_e_g_ 32.944552,-97.129767>&types=point_of_interest&radius=<RADIUS_IN_METERS>&sensor=false&key=<YOUR_APP_KEY>&pagetoken=<TOKEN_FOR_NEXT_PAGE_FROM_next_page_token_TAG_OF_RESPONSE>
```

And don't forget to enable Places API for your application from [Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend).

**For p.2:**

Use info from p.1 ([Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)) and suggested by [Vadim Eksler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7917629/vadim-eksler) in his comment [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) in Google Maps Android Custom Info Window like in [this](http://www.zoftino.com/google-maps-android-custom-info-window-example) example:

> ```
> public class CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
>
>     private Context context;
>
>     public CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(Context ctx){
>         context = ctx;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
>         View view = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater()
> .inflate(R.layout.map_custom_infowindow, null);
>
>         TextView name_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
>         TextView details_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.details);
>         ImageView img = view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
>
>         TextView hotel_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.hotels);
>         TextView food_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.food);
>         TextView transport_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.transport);
>
>         name_tv.setText(marker.getTitle());
>         details_tv.setText(marker.getSnippet());
>
>         InfoWindowData infoWindowData = (InfoWindowData) marker.getTag();
>
>         int imageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(infoWindowData.getImage().toLowerCase(),
>                 "drawable", context.getPackageName());
>         img.setImageResource(imageId);
>
>         hotel_tv.setText(infoWindowData.getHotel());
>         food_tv.setText(infoWindowData.getFood());
>         transport_tv.setText(infoWindowData.getTransport());
>
>         return view;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: P1 is a very nice workaround but in my case it can be problematic, some places are very distinct places. We decided to use our custom markers. P2, Since this is only way, we are on it. Thanks for the complete answer.

Comment: @kelalaka You're welcome! P1 As your wish. Place Search can return  very distinct places and you can filter it.