# Place tap listener on Google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have an android app with a map fragment.
The map displays places and I am looking for a way to add a listener to get that place when the user taps on them.

The most relevant information I found was a suggestion to add a listener for clicks to the map, get the long&lat and then search for a place based on that.
I thought I could do that using `FetchPlaceRequest` but this also seems to require a `placeId` in the first place when instantiating.

Am I missing something really basic?

EDIT

The code for the fragment containing the map (I thought implementing PlaceSelectionlistener would do the work)

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
PlaceSelectionListener, KoinComponent {

private lateinit var mapViewModel: MapViewModel
private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
private var locationRequest: LocationRequest? = null
private var locationCallback: LocationCallback? = null
private val permissionsUtils : PermissionsUtils by inject()
private val preferencesUtils : PreferencesUtils by inject { parametersOf(activity!!.applicationContext)}
private var root : View? = null
private val defaultZoom : Float = 16f

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    mapViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MapViewModel::class.java)
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)

    if (canAccessLocation()) {
        initialiseMap(true)
    } else {
        val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

        requestPermissions(permissions, PermissionRequests.FineLocation.value)
    }

    return root
}

override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?) = false

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    map = googleMap

    map.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions
        .loadRawResourceStyle(activity!!.applicationContext, preferencesUtils.mapMode))

    map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

    if (canAccessLocation()){
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        map.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
    }

    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                        permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when (requestCode) {

        PermissionRequests.FineLocation.value -> {
            val permissionGranted = grantResults.isNotEmpty()
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

            initialiseMap(permissionGranted)
        }
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    fusedLocationClient?.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    requestLocationUpdates()
}

override fun onPlaceSelected(status: Place) {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(activity!!.applicationContext,""+ status!!.name + status!!.latLng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
    toast.show()
}

override fun onError(status: Status) {
    Toast.makeText(activity!!.applicationContext,"" + status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show()
}

private fun initialiseMap(withLocation: Boolean) {
    val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    if (!withLocation) {
        return
    }

    requestLocationUpdates()
}

private fun requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (fusedLocationClient == null) {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity!!.applicationContext)
    }

    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            val locationList = locationResult.locations

            if (locationList.size > 0) {
                val location = locationList[locationList.size - 1]
                val latLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)

                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, defaultZoom))
            }
        }
    }

    fusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())

    locationRequest = LocationRequest()
    locationRequest?.interval = 1800000
    locationRequest?.fastestInterval = 1800000
    locationRequest?.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY

    fusedLocationClient?.lastLocation?.addOnCompleteListener(Activity()) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful && task.result != null) {
                val latLong = LatLng(task.result!!.latitude, task.result!!.longitude)
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, defaultZoom))
            }
        }
}

private fun canAccessLocation(): Boolean {
    return permissionsUtils.hasPermission(activity!!.applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you already have. It would be a place for other to start looking to help you. [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't manage places that shown on `MapView` (`MapFragment`) and it's markers not clickable (and customizable) IMHO better way is to hide "default" place markers via [Google Maps styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090477/6950238) answer of [Jozef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4239860/jozef):

> 1. Create JSON file **src\main\res\raw\map_style.json** like this:
>
> ```
> [
>   {
>     featureType: "poi",
>     elementType: "labels",
>     stylers: [
>       {
>         visibility: "off"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```
>
> 2. Add map style to your `GoogleMap`
>
> ```
> googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style));
> ```

and then - get nearby places via [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) from [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) URL request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<LAT_LNG>&types=point_of_interest&radius=<RADIUS_IN_METERS>&sensor=false&key=<YOUR_APP_KEY>
```

parse it and show desired places on map programmatically as customizable and clickable Google Maps markers. That approach allows to you not only process marker clicks via default [`onMarkerClick()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener), but to manage quantity and types of places, marker icons design etc. There is also no need to create a request and process its response every time a user clicks on map.

NB! Nearby URL request returns only 20 places, for load more data you should use string value from `next_page_token` tag of response and pass it via `pagetoken` parameter for next request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<LAT_LNG>&types=point_of_interest&radius=<RADIUS_IN_METERS>&sensor=false&key=<YOUR_APP_KEY>&pagetoken=<TOKEN_FOR_NEXT_PAGE_FROM_next_page_token_TAG_OF_RESPONSE>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now, thanks. Never thought there wasn't an out of the box way of clicking on all the POIs and getting details about them without much effort