# Get a list of POIs (Points Of Interest) currently visible on a GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, point-of-interest

Using the [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/overview), is it possible to get a list of all the POI's currently visible as "icons" on the map?

I know I can use the Places API to do something similar, but in my case I really just want to get the exact POI's that are currently visible as icons on the users screen at this moment.

I also know that I can listen for when the user taps on a POI, but this won't help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems its impossible via Google Maps SDK, but anyway you can use workaround:

1. Remove all "POI's currently visible as "icons" on the map" like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090477/6950238) answer of [josef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4239860/jozef):

a) create JSON file src\main\res\raw\map_style.json like this:

```
[
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      {
        visibility: "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

b) add map style to your GoogleMap:

```
`googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style));`
```

2. Get coordinates of area visible on screen:

   `LatLngBounds visibleAreaBounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;`
3. Get information about POI's "manually" (by kinds of them) near screen center coordinates via [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/overview) and parse information about each place.

4.For each POI's coordinates check if it exactly inside bounds:

```
for (LatLng poiCoords : PoisCoords) {
    if (visibleAreaBounds.contains(poiCoords)) {
        // POI is visible on screen 
    }
}
```