# How to remove default markers in google-maps-react-markers?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I am using `google-maps-react-markers` library and I want to remove all default markers before drawing my markers on map. But I couldn't find options.

Is there any way I can remove them or is it just not possible?

I tried to implement by using map styles but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538668/17985195

Comment: @TIP95 Thanks for your answer. I tried with that solution but couldn't implement with https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react-markers

Comment: There's an ongoing issue with regards to removing these POIs in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/321086844